# Does sendgrid supports sending email with "multiple" attachments using sendgrid web API (xml) and C# HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: email-attachments, sendgrid

When I try to send only one attachment, it works fine however when I try to send multiple attachments, it does not work.

Comment: Yes, we do support multiple attachments.  Could you share some code so I can help you debug?

Comment: Sharing the code will be a bit difficult for now. Need to check with some people first. However can you please tell me what header should I add in between two attachments? I tried adding boundary and the header as <code>-----------------------------ccbtkg59th7sed
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[PatientInformation.txt]"; filename="PatientInformation.txt";
Content-Type: application/octet-stream</code> in between two attachments.